# EnumWindows doesnt show apps from windows 8 metro

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a program that uses this code:

```
EnumWindows eW = new EnumWindows();
eW.GetWindows();
```

and a foreach loop.  However, this only returns the Windows Desktop apps and no Metro apps. Is  there any way to find all opened windows with metro apps?  Also, how do I find the Metro launcher.  How could I do this?

Comment: No. Metro apps and Desktop apps run in seperate environments and neither shell ever meet. (This is asked regularly here but I can't find one to hand)

Comment: They are just not displayed in a window.  Some functionality is available from the IAppVisibility interface, not what you want.

Comment: I need the windows preperties as is size, title etc... This is basic info for next loop, where I start a snag windows elements like as buttons, areas etc.. Is any way how to do it? How can I find the running apps in metro enviroment? thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could find running processes?

Comment: But it is not enough, becouse I need to know window preperties. Sizes, titles, positions...After I got this infos, next part of program will scann everzthing in window..buttons, areas, cursors ets... and will make a "copy" consists of .png images, whish is next released to flash... For me is important to find apps like as ALT+TAB view... It's possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a manifest file to your application and set uiaccess=true

Microsofts guide: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx

Using EnumWindows in an application with uiaccess flag set to true will yield all the windows in alt-tab and then some more (that you might want to filter out).